# How can I center a headline in CSS?

Tags: html, css, center, text-align

Newbie here with a simple (and no doubt dumb) question.

I’m trying to center a headline. I tried using the text-align property in CSS but to no avail:

```
h1 {
     text-align: center;
}
```

The headline is still flush left.

After doing a bit of digging, I tried this:

```
h1 {
     margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Still no luck. I then tried putting the headline into a DIV with the id "headline":

```
#headline {
     text-align: center;
}
```

And, when that still didn't work, I tried:

```
#headline {
     margin: 0 auto;
}
```

No luck.

I then came across a previous discussion about centering a DIV in CSS. One poster said that "a  element fills 100% of parent element's width. If you want to center it, then the first thing you have to do is make it less than 100% wide. So set a width on the div, 200px or something."

When I tried

```
#headline {
     width: 1200px;
     margin: 0 auto;
}
```

nothing happened.

But when I tried:

```
#headline {
     width: 1200px;
     text-align: center;
}
```

the headline did shift to the center. The thing is, it isn't perfectly centered.

I've tried adjusting the width. That helps some but when I make the window bigger or smaller, the headline is no longer centered.

Any suggestions?

Apologies in advance for any inadvertent *faux pas* (this is my first time posting). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have any other CSS code which could interfere with your styles? text-align:center is enough to center a text in any block.

Comment: `text-align: center;` should have worked. Some other CSS must be creating problems. Can you please create a JSFiddle or CodePen example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the width `100%` instead of a fixed pixel width. This is the default value (for a block element such as `<h1>`, but you must have changed something.) This will make it dynamic.

See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/jlam55555/jcdstceg/) on JSFiddle.net.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted? What is wrong?

Answer (score 4):

By default, this will be centered:

```css
h1 {
     text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Test</h1>
```

While there are a variety of ways it could be acting up, the most likely candidate is that you have set `h1 { display: inline }` (or something other than `block`) elsewhere in your code.  Try giving the `h1` a background colour or `outline: 2px solid #0f0` to see where the layout bounds are.

Firefox and Chrome also have great developer tools, so inspecting the `h1` will show you where all styles are coming from.  You can go through and uncheck styles until you arrive at the culprit.

Answer (score 3):

The first CSS you posted works fine, if it doesn't you must have some other CSS that's overriding it.

```css
h1 {
     text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Centered Headline</h1>
```